# Want figure here but

Tags: floats, wrap

Don' t how to place a non-floating figure here. If wrapfigure is used then it can be placed correctly, but then the text wants to wrap. I don't want that.

Comment: I think your question is incomplete. Please include minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: I guess http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text answers your question?

Comment: Ah, you're using LyX? Go into the settings of the float inset, uncheck *use default settings*,  and choose *Here Definitely*.